# Putty FindwindowEx "Edit" Childwindows

Tags: vb.net, childwindow, findwindowex

I am trying to use API FindwindowEx to input an IP address inside the Putty textbox. I know the textbox window is call "Edit", problem is there are three "Edit" Window in the Putty parent window.

Is there a way to separate the three "Edit" childwindows out so I am only sending text to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can specify anything in `FindWindowEx` that will differentiate between the different Edit child windows. You could call `GetWindowsRect` with the handle of each of the child windows and find the one that is positioned in the top left of the form. You could also call `GetWindowLength` - that would remove the Port edit box easily enough (as it is shorter than the other two on the form).

The IP address edit box always appears first as I iterate through the child windows. Not sure you can guarantee that though.